# Google Analytics Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am sending an HTTP post request to a custom report in Google Analytics, that I have created. The OAuth2.0 authentication works fine, and I get my access token. But when sending the custom report request I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The user I use for OAuth is the same user that has created the custom report, so I do not know how can I not have sufficient authentication scopes.

This is a request header I do not understand:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/ https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default"
```

I have tried this same thing with other account and I don't receive this response header, so I assume it is related to the error.

Thanks.